# Match a set of characters from one table into the records of an other table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables (T-SQL):

```
tblInvalidCharactersList         tblMonthsRecords
+-----------+-----------+        +--------+-------------+       
| CodePoint | Character |        | RecRef | Name        |
+-----------+-----------+        +--------+-------------+
|    38     |     &     |        | 21     | Firs> name  |
+-----------+-----------+        +--------+-------------+
|    64     |     @     |        | 89     | @Second name|
+-----------+-----------+        +--------+-------------+
|    62     |     >     |        | 321    | Third n«me  |
+-----------+-----------+        +--------+-------------+
|    171    |     «     |        | 381    | Fourth name |
+-----------+-----------+        +--------+-------------+
```

I want to find those records of the `tblMonthsRecords` which have at least  one (or more) character(s) from the `Character` column of the `tblInvalidCharactersList` table.

I tried:

```
SELECT 
    [RecRef],
    [Name]
FROM [tblMonthsRecords]
WHERE [Name] IN (SELECT Character FROM [tblInvalidCharactersList])
```

and it returns no results at all.

I even tried the `NOT IN` clause and as you may guess, returns all records.

The reason why I am not hardcoding the characters list within a `LIKE` clause is because I want the list to be dynamically updated.

You can think the `tblInvalidCharactersList` as a characters "black list".

Comment: Don't  you [like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `exists`:

```
select mr.*
from tblMonthsRecords mr
where exists (select 1
              from tblInvalidCharactersList icl
              where charindex(icl.Character, mr.name) > 0
             );
```

You don't seem to care about the actual invalid character.

Comment: Exactly, I am indifferent of the invalid character and your answer is more accurate and faster than the other one.

Comment: If I had to deal with Unicode data would I have to prefix my string with an `N` and if yes, like so is correct: `'N' + mr.name + ''`?

Comment: @mchar . . . Not at all.  If you are dealing with national character sets, then the columns should *both* be declared as `nvarchar()`, and the code should just work.

Answer (score 1):

`IN` will look for exact character match in `Name` column it will not search for the character in `Name` column

Use `LIKE` operator

```
select Distinct a.* 
from tblMonthsRecords a
join tblInvalidCharactersList b 
  on a.Name like '%' + b.Character + '%'
```

Another way using `charindex`

```
charindex(b.Character,a.Name) > 0
```

Comment: [charindex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) seems to work-under testing. The `Like` approach however is getting slow because of the double returning records and `DISTINCT`does not seem to help.

Comment: So, I need to `Distinct` either using `LIKE` or not. `JOIN` seems to return duplicates and is slower in comparison to the other answer.

Comment: @mchar - Yes, Gordan's answer is better in this case. It will not return duplicates.